# Incluir classe conforme link

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma `div` que irá conter em seu **hover** uma cor específica, essa cor irá depender do `a` que existe acima dela.

```css
.homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../imagens/engenhariaPNG.png");
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
.homeNoticias li:hover .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    display: block;
}
.homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia {
    background-image: url("../imagens/engenhariaPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticiasOpacidadeHospitalar {
    background-image: url("../imagens/hospitalarPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticiasOpacidadeElevadores {
    background-image: url("../imagens/elevadoresPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticiasOpacidadeIluminacao {
    background-image: url("../imagens/IluminacaoPNG.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="homeNoticias margin-top-40">
    <li>
      <div class="p-relative"> 
        <a href="/engenharia">
          <div class="homeNoticiasOpacidade homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia"></div>
          <img src="./imagens/noticias1.jpg" height="305" width="250" alt="" title="" />
          <div class="homeNoticiasFundo">
            <span class="homeNoticiasData">03/09/2014</span>
            <span class="homeNoticiasDescricao">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, meis omnes ei cum, solet.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a href="#" class="flechaPreta flechaBranca p-absolute bottom-20"></a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>   
  <li>
    <div class="p-relative"> 
      <a href="/hospitalar">
        <div class="homeNoticiasOpacidade homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia"></div>
        <img src="./imagens/noticias1.jpg" height="305" width="250" alt="" title="" />
        <div class="homeNoticiasFundo">
          <span class="homeNoticiasData">03/09/2014</span>
          <span class="homeNoticiasDescricao">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, meis omnes ei cum, solet.</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <a href="#" class="flechaPreta flechaBranca p-absolute bottom-20"></a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

O que eu quero fazer?
Quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima da `li` que tem o `a` **/engenharia** ele adiciona a classe `homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia` à classe `homeNoticiasOpacidade`. Ou, se tiver o **/hospitalar** ele inclui a classe `homeNoticiasOpacidadeHospitalar` Como eu poderia fazer isso?

O `(window.location.toString().indexOf('/engenharia') > 0)` funcionaria?

Comment: Você quer "montar" o nome da classe conforme o link, é isso? (ex.: se tem `/engenharia` vira `homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia`, se tem `/hospitalar` vira `homeNoticiasOpacidadeHospitalar` etc)

Comment: Isso mesmo @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso somente com CSS:

```css
.homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../imagens/engenhariaPNG.png");
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
.homeNoticias li:hover .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    display: block;
}
.homeNoticias li:hover a[href="/engenharia"] .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    background-image: url("../imagens/engenhariaPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticias li:hover a[href="/hospitalar"] .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    background-image: url("../imagens/hospitalarPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticias li:hover a[href="/elevadores"] .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    background-image: url("../imagens/elevadoresPNG.png");
}
.homeNoticias li:hover a[href="/iluminacao"] .homeNoticiasOpacidade {
    background-image: url("../imagens/IluminacaoPNG.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="homeNoticias margin-top-40">
    <li>
      <div class="p-relative"> 
        <a href="/engenharia">
          <div class="homeNoticiasOpacidade homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia"></div>
          <img src="./imagens/noticias1.jpg" height="305" width="250" alt="" title="" />
          <div class="homeNoticiasFundo">
            <span class="homeNoticiasData">03/09/2014</span>
            <span class="homeNoticiasDescricao">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, meis omnes ei cum, solet.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a href="#" class="flechaPreta flechaBranca p-absolute bottom-20"></a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>   
  <li>
    <div class="p-relative"> 
      <a href="/hospitalar">
        <div class="homeNoticiasOpacidade homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia"></div>
        <img src="./imagens/noticias1.jpg" height="305" width="250" alt="" title="" />
        <div class="homeNoticiasFundo">
          <span class="homeNoticiasData">03/09/2014</span>
          <span class="homeNoticiasDescricao">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, meis omnes ei cum, solet.</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <a href="#" class="flechaPreta flechaBranca p-absolute bottom-20"></a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Isso é possível nesse caso pois o elemento ao qual você quer aplicar o estilo está dentro do link. Então é só selecionar pelo atributo `href` e dentro dele achar a `div` com a classe certa.

(Eu não estou adicionando a classe como pedido na pergunta, somente aplicando o estilo diretamente ao elemento, descartando a classe. Se você precisa dessa classe por outros motivos, desconsidere essa resposta.)

Comment: Excelente! E, se houver alguma coisa após o link, exemplo **http://www.meusite.com.br/engenharia/blablabla.html** terá problema?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Nesse caso, use `href^="..."` em vez de `=` - assim você estará selecionando por prefixo.

Comment: Nota 10 cara, não sabia que podia informar links no CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Por partes:

> Quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima da li que tem o a /engenharia (...)

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
    var li = $(this); 
    if(li.contains("a[href='/engenharia']")) {
        // SUA LÓGICA AQUI
    }      
});
```

> (...) ele adiciona a classe homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia à classe homeNoticiasOpacidade

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    if(li.contains("a[href='/engenharia']")) {
        var div = li.find('homeNoticiasOpacidade');
        div.addClass('homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia');
    }
});
```

Comment: Não seria `$("li a:[href='/engenharia']").mouseover...` ?

Comment: Sim, se for só esse li o alvo. Como a classe homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia também está no outro li, que tem outro href, considerei que a necessidade era mais genérica.

Comment: @bfavaretto excelente resposta. Todavia, eu esqueci de um detalhe. Eu tenho 4 situações, citei duas na minha pergunta. Exemplo: se for **/engenharia** adiciona `homeNoticiasOpacidadeEngenharia` se for **/hospitalar** adiciona `homeNoticiasOpacidadeHospitalar`

Comment: @FelipeStoker Tem certeza de que precisa dessas classes tão específicas? Parece que você está complicando mais que o necessário. Vou editar a resposta e explicar como tratar isso, mas considere mexer no HTML e no CSS para não precisar de classes assim.

Comment: Irei sim. Serão 4 classes, que possuem quatro cores em um PNG transparente, para 4 setores da empresa.

Comment: Agora que vi a resposta do mgibsonbr, @FelipeStoker. A reorganização do CSS é algo como o que ele sugeriu mesmo, criando regras específicas para classes que existam dentro de outras. Inclusive eu evitaria depender do href, colocando classes como "engenharia" direto no li e me baseando nelas.

Comment: @bfavaretto perfeita sua resposta, funcionou. A do mgibsonbr também funcionou apenas com CSS.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu entendo sua posição, o que acontece, é que são itens fixos e não gerenciáveis, então acredito não ter problema em informar manualmente.